# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key 'Item' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, oop

I'm trying to implement a basic sprite game in C#. I'm testing to see if two dictionaries are equal to each other and I'm having an issue with Containskey() as well as my Equals function in the sprite class.

```
public class Sprite
{
    private Point p;
    private uint Horiz;
    private uint Vert;
    private uint Health;
    private uint Shield;
    private Dictionary<Item, int> inv;
    private string[] QuickSlots;

    /* Default constructor
     * set all values to 0
     */
    //string[] empty;
    //string [] mt;
    public Sprite()
    {
        Point newpoint = new Point();
        newpoint.SetX(0);
        newpoint.SetY(0);
        newpoint.SetZ(0);
        p = newpoint;
        Horiz = 0;
        Vert = 0;
        Health = 0;
        Shield = 0;
        inv = null;
        QuickSlots = null;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)(p.GetX() ^ (p.GetY() << 8) ^ (p.GetZ() << 16) ^
            Horiz ^ (Vert << 9) ^ 
            (Health << 18) ^ (Shield << 25));
    }

    public bool DictionaryEquals(Dictionary<Item, int> inv2)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<Item, int> entry in inv2)
        {
            if(inv.ContainsKey(entry.Key)) //(inv[entry.Key] == inv2[entry.Key]))
            {
                if((inv[entry.Key] == inv2[entry.Key]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        //Check for null and compare run-time types.
            if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else 
        {
                Sprite s = (Sprite) obj;
            //   this.PrintInventory();
                s.PrintInventory();
            return 
                ((p.Equals(s.p)) &&
                (inv.Equals(s.inv)) &&
                //(QuickSlots == s.QuickSlots) &&
                (Horiz == s.Horiz) &&
                (Vert == s.Vert) &&
                (Health == s.Health) &&
                (Shield == s.Shield));
            }
    }

    public bool HasItem(string item)
    {
        return inv.ContainsKey(StringtoItem(item, this));
    }

    public void TakeItem(string item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Does this even work\n");
        if(HasItem(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Does this even work2\n");
            int x = inv[StringtoItem(item, this)] - 1;
            if(x > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Does this even work3\n");
                inv[StringtoItem(item, this)] = x;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Does this even work4\n");
                inv.Remove(StringtoItem(item, this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the dictionary.Equals() function works correctly but none of my testSprites match my expected Sprites because when I use an item, it doesn't decrement correctly from the testSprite inventory. The takeItem function calls the hasItem function to check if a dictionary/inventory has an item and it always returns false because the containskey function is always returning false even though I know for a fact that the dictionary contains the key when print out the contents of the dictionary to the console.

Below is the Item.cs file.

```
public class Item
{
        private string name;
        protected Sprite holder;

        public Item(string n, Sprite h)
        //, int hc, int sc, int ec,
        //      uint mh, uint ms, bool i, uint s, uint md)
        {
                name = n;
                holder = h;
        }

        public string GetItemName()
        {
            return name;
        }
   
        public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)(name.GetHashCode() ^ (holder.GetPoint().GetX() << 8) ^ (holder.GetPoint().GetY() << 16) ^ 
            (holder.GetPoint().GetZ() << 16) ^
            holder.GetHoriz() ^ (holder.GetVert() << 9) ^ 
            (holder.GetHealth() << 18) ^ (holder.GetShield() << 25));
    }




        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        //Check for null and compare run-time types.
            if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else 
        {
                Item i = (Item) obj;
            return 
                ((name == i.name) &&
                (holder.Equals(i.holder)));
            }
    }
}
```

I suspect that something is wrong with one of the GetHashCode functions but I am not entirely sure how to fix it so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`==` is used for referential equality (for reference types, like Item which is a class), but seems that what you need here is structural equality - so `inv[entry.Key] == inv2[entry.Key]` will fail - try `inv[entry.Key].Equals(inv2[entry.Key])` (you did override Equals and GetHashCode already according to your structural equality logic).
You could have also make `public class Item : IEquatable<Item>` as a bonus :)

Comment: Okay I'll try that. thanks

Comment: Sure, let me know the results!
I would suggest you can also edit the question to include the code calling these classes.

Comment: @blub_9 I've corrected my post, the interfaces I've mentioned earlier is not mandatory.

Comment: I ended up including the private string name in my gethashcode function and that got rid of the error. Thank you though